# Jenkins BUILD FAILED/CANCELLED on openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I have problems pushing new code to my openshift application with jenkins. I have enabled jenkins from web console admin and it works(no custom settings). However I have to push at least 2 times before it pushes new changes to my app.
I have bronze plan. I use 3 apps (main app, database app, jenkins) and when pushing, jenkins creates 4th app.
Pushing new version of app takes a long time, since I upgrade search index after every push. When I push for the first time, this is what I get:

```
git push origin
Counting objects: 38, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (20/20), 2.33 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 20 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Syncing git content to other proxy gears
remote: Executing Jenkins build.
remote: 
remote: You can track your build at https://jenkins-myapp.rhcloud.com/job/digrin-build
remote: 
remote: Waiting for build to schedule.....................................................................
remote: **BUILD FAILED/CANCELLED**
remote: Please see the Jenkins log for more details via 'rhc tail'
remote: !!!!!!!!
remote: Deployment Halted!
remote: If the build failed before the deploy step, your previous
remote: build is still running.  Otherwise, your application may be
remote: partially deployed or inaccessible.
remote: Fix the build and try again.
remote: !!!!!!!!
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control post-receive' for /var/lib/openshift/55a0310e4...4/jenkins-client
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
```

This is my second push:

```
$ git push origin
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 481 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Syncing git content to other proxy gears
remote: Executing Jenkins build.
remote: 
remote: You can track your build at https://jenkins-myapp.rhcloud.com/job/digrin-build
remote: 
remote: Waiting for build to schedule......Done
remote: Waiting for job to complete.............................................................................................................................................................................Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: .................................Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: ............................................................................................Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: ..................................................Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: ................................................................Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: ........................................Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: ........Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: ..................................Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: .........................................................................................................Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: .....Retrying job 3 lookup....Done.
remote: ...............................................................................................................Done
remote: SUCCESS
remote: New build has been deployed.
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://55a000094@digrin-myapp.rhcloud.com/~/git/digrin.git/
   af390d4..f47120e  master -> master
```

Why my first push always fails? I do not see any error regarding jenkins in `rhc tail myapp`

Comment: Try logging into your Jenkins web console and looking at the build log to see if there is any more useful information there that you can use to determine the issue, or post here for others to try and help you.

Comment: I see only 4 builds and all were successful. I'll check console log on next push. Maybe jenkins finishes the job, but git raises error?

Comment: I tried to push new version again to openshift. Same error on first push. Jenkins log is empty and I can not see new build anywhere in jenkins web console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I **push first** commit, it yells `BUILD FAILED/CANCELLED`. On **second push** it is a success. If I do **third push** right after second, it is success too. Almost like jenkins app would hibernate, but it cannot. I have bronze plan and I tried to load jenkins url so I was sure jenkins app is running.
Only possible reason for first failed push that I can think of is that I have 3 out of 16 apps and probably 4th app creation takes too long and Jenkins does not wait and ends with error.

**So I will just keep doing two pushes instead of one every time I want to push new version of my app.**