# Best way to deploy Django app to OpenShift without downtime?

Tags: django, deployment, jenkins, openshift, web-deployment

I have been pushing new versions of my Django app to OpenShift for some time now. At first I used **general `git push`** command. But later on I had to add some long running deploy commands. Well long story short it took like half an hour to complete deployment -> my app was unavailable.
So I enabled **Jenkins**, but [first push always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656889/jenkins-build-failed-cancelled-on-openshift) and app is also unavailable for some time. Jenkins runs on one gear, creates new gear and I always have 4 gears running. (one is paid, because Jenkins does not work properly and stays alive for some time)
I've read that **hot [deploy](https://www.openshift.com/sites/default/files/documents/OpenShift-2.0-User_Guide-en-US_5.pdf)** (page 40) might also work without downtimes, but I am afraid about consistency(not sure where to read more about it).
So, there are these 3 options how to push to OpenShift. Is there any third party service I might use?

**How to push to OpenShift to minimize downtime and potentially number of gears used?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've pretty much answered you own question, go for hot deployment if you need continuous delivery on your app.

I'm not sure what are your concerns about consistency, but if you have them, then use Jenkins for the original CI purpose, and only then if everything is OK, you can push it to production using hot deployment.

Basically, I'd have such a workflow:

1. Make changes and commit them
2. Push it to [Jenkins CI server](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-continuous-integration.html), check if the tests and build are passing
3. Push the build to your gears using [hot deployment](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-modifying-applications.html#hot-deployment)

Comment: I used jenkins in default settings, where app was unavailable for some time. I guess bigger clients need to push to openshift without downtime. Thanks for your answer, I'll try hot deployment.